# Access file in production by Handler giving "access denied"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, permission-denied

I have a legacy web app, which has a HTTPHandler to give access to a set of files by checking permissions in database.

In development it works OK.

But in production, it works **only** in localhost. Every another computer that try to access file (and should read it) throws an exception:

> Access to the path 'G:\Sites\Portal\Portals\0\attachments' is denied.

At line:

```
Dim bufferArquivo As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(request.PhysicalPath)
```

It denies access to folder where file is located, but I've checked **it has full permissions to Everyone**.

I'm not using impersonation, so I'm thinking if could be it. If yes, how can I implement?

It happens after migrate website from IIS6 to II7. (works on iis6, does not in iis7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly happens, but before migrating to IIS7, `request.PhysicalPath` was returning full filename path (full path + filename). After, it was returing only the folder containing the file (full path). I had to insert filename to `request.PhysicalPath` to work as nefore.

```
Dim filename As String = request.Path.Substring(request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
Dim bufferArquivo As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(request.PhysicalPath + "\" + filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check which user is used by the ApplicationPool for the application. If it's set to ApplicationPoolIdentity you need to look up, to which user ApplicationPoolIdentity is mapped to.

You could also set the Identity to NetworkService and give read permissions on that folder for the NetworkService. Worked for me 100% at multiple servers.

Comment: Saying set the identity to "NetworkService" you mean using Impersonation?

Comment: Still not working, can be something related to HTTP Handlers registering?